# How to keep a separate database for each user in asp mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I keep a separate database for each user, I check the database from the master database and get the database name of that user, and change the ConnString in the context class, but when multiple users log in, the last user's database is being processed. How can I solve this problem?

```
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(string database) : 
        base(("Server=localhost;port=3306;Database="+ database+ 
        ";uid=root;password=;charset=utf8;"))
        {
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new 
             MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration());
        }
        ..
        ..
    }
```

The above code fragment is inside the context class. I am changing the connectionStrings in web.config.

Comment: Why you do such thing? What is the actual requirement?

Comment: You shouldn't be changing the web.config at all.  Let it have the connection string for the master database and then build the user connection string from what's in the master database.  Each controller should instantiate a new Dbcontext with the correct connection string for the user.  Just be aware that by having different DBs for each user you will be losing the benefit of connection pooling.  Every user will have a connection rather than sharing them as needed.  If it's not a requirement to have separate DBs, don't.  Just organize the data in the DB to be separated.

Comment: @EmreSavcı You will sell a project to more than one person, and all of these people must have a separate database.Think of it like this.

Comment: Do you sell project physically with environment (host, database etc) or you are hosting and only selling service itself? If you maintain services like database, you can make your project to work compatible with multitenant.

Comment: Why not use a lookup table instead of a table for every user, that doesn't seem to be scalable

Comment: @G.LC Do not say for each user, a database for each business.

Comment: I'm confused, so you have a database which has all the user info (a lookup table) then you just want to use that info to change the connection string which links to a different database? Database for each business?

Comment: Probably talking about [Multi tenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns)?

Comment: @G.LC yes, database for each corporation